# How to get data from the server when the Android app is closed when using the service and display in the notification

Tags: android, service, server, notifications

How to get data from the server when the Android app is closed when using the **service** and **display** in the **notification**
Example :
I'll design a program that communicates with the server every few seconds and displays the values received in the **notification**. Even when the program is closed or when the phone is turned on, it still has the information exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a service using startForeground to prevent it from being killed.

However

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory.

But still if you just want to send a notification you can integrate firebase in your server to show the notifications.

Notifications can even be shown when the app is not running in the background.

Setting up firebase in your android application:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: no,get data for server database and save to application.

Answer (score 0):

Since the inception of Android Oreo, `services` are killed as soon as Application gets in background state. You could use `Foreground Service` to avoid getting killed but that will display a persistent notification to the user.

Going by your needs, I would suggest you to use [`WorkerManager`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#java). It will choose best `JobScheduler` for you, and can perform task repeatedly as per your needs.